# Changing default python version in Debian — library import issue

Tags: python, installation

I have some code that I wish to run using Python 2.7.3 and unfortunately I cannot get Debian to accomplish that. The issue is that I cannot import some libraries on newly installed Python 2.7.3 on Debian. (Debain originally had 2.6.x)

I have to run some crypto code on Debian that I wish to run using Python 2.7.3. Unfortunately, the import for M2Crypto fails on Python 2.7.3 but works fine on 2.6(.x).

Just pointing an alias to python2.7 will not work as the libraries are not properly getting installed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

It's not a particularly good idea to change the system Python - *lots* of other stuff depends on it. Instead, use [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org) to install the libraries you need:

```
$ pip-2.7 install M2Crypto
```

Comment: But I don't want to install binaries for 2.6. I wish to install them for 2.7. Apparently, I don't have any such utility called pip-2.7

Comment: Presumably the python-pip package for your Debian (Sid?) isn't smart enough to hook into the python-2.7 package, then. You can install pip yourself to get round that ... instructions are available at the link in my answer.

Comment: Well, there's not much in the system. It's a simple VM I am giving out to people. Can you simply tell me how to install 2.7.3 such that any libraries that are added to the machine, get added to 2.7.3 and not other python versions?